# Conversion from XML to Json removes 0 in Azure Data Factory copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am converting XML files to Json(gzip compression) using Azure Data Factory copy activity.

However , I observe that in the XML file I have the values stored as 0123456789. However , when this is converted to Json it is saved as "value" : 123456789. Without 0.

I would like to keep the Json values as-is from the XML . Please provide suggestions for the same.

PS: I can't use data flow and I can't modifiy the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uncheck the detect data type in the copy activity

[image]